# I want to move to another screen only by comparing the role name which basically I get from database through webapi...is there any way to do so?

Tags: swift, webapi

this one is login button action code ...what I actually want is this if I click over login button if its (agent)<--(its r_name) then it should move to the next screen ......response variable contain all the data from database I just want to get r_name from that response variable thats it

```
@IBAction func btnLogin(_ sender: Any) {

//normally it moves to the next screen by applying below code but I want to compare roles name if e.g role name="agent" then move to another screen
        
         let response = mm.alluser(phoneNo: txtPhoneNumber.text!, Password: txtPassword.text!)
        if response.count ?? 0 > 0
        {                         
            let next : tabViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabViewController") as! tabViewController
             self.navigationController?.pushViewController(next, animated: true)
           showalertforloginsuccess()
            print("Login Successfull")
        }else
        {
            showalertforloginfail()
            print("Not Login")
        }
    }
```

//Here is a class userModel contain role property

```
public class UserModel:Codable
{
    
    public var u_id: Int = 0
    public var u_name: String?=""
    public var phoneNumber: String?=""
    public var address: String? = ""
    public var password: String? = ""
    public var r_id: Int? = 0
    public var r_name: String? = ""
    
}
```

//User manager class interacting with web api through function named ( alluser )

```
class Usersmanager
{
    
    var apiwrapper=APIWrapper()
    var decoder=JSONDecoder()
    var encoder=JSONEncoder()
    var Message=""
    
    public func alluser(phoneNo: String, Password : String)->[UserModel]
    {
        var users:[UserModel]=[]
        let result=apiwrapper.getMethodCall(controllerName: "user", actionName: "Userlogin?phoneNo=\(phoneNo)&Password=\(Password)")
      
        if result.ResponseCode==200{
            
            guard let data=result.ResponseData
                else{
                    
                    Message=result.ResponseMessage
                    return users
            }
            //data is now valid
            users = try! decoder.decode([UserModel].self,from: data)
        }
        else {
            
            Message=result.ResponseMessage
        }
        return users
    }  
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. However, you don't give us any information on where the `role` property comes from, so we can't help you figure out *how* to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: role property comes from userModel class I'm attaching the userModel class and user manager class which is actually interacting with webapi to get the data from database

Comment: Note the formatting problems with the changes to your code. I fixed the code formatting on your initial question. You should edit your question to move the new code inside the triple back-tick code markers so that it formats properly.

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution ?

Comment: I have formatted code correctly now you can read it and do share with me solution if u have a time

Comment: I don't see how your getMethodCall function can work. Network calls should be asynchronous, so I would expect that function to take a completion handler rather than returning a function result.

Comment: why I'm unable to get the r_name(role name ) from that function even its return type is UserModel means it returns all the properties of userModel class when function is called...